# Is there a logical condition which checks if a dataframe belongs to a list of nested lists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists

My question is quite general. I have a list of nested lists of dataframes with the following structure:

[image]

I want a logical condition which checks if the dataframe `TransitTypes[["TransitType1"]][["driver1"]][[1]]` belongs to the list `TransitTypes[["TransitType1"]]` in order to use it in a user-defined fuction.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you get `TransitTypes[["TransitType1"]][["driver1"]][[1]]`in the first place? If you get it like this then you know it because of your own indexing. If you have an arbitrary data.frame and want to check if it is identical to any data.frame in `TransitTypes[["TransitType1"]]` you can check it using `identical()`.

Comment: I think you just want `if (!is.null(TransitTypes[["TransitType1"]][["driver1"]][[1]])) ...`